# How do you remove the 0 when using printf, .precision on float type

Tags: c, printf, precision

I have this line of code:

`printf("%.3d%.2f\n", ones, value);`

However, this doesn't work ,because the  `%.2f` produces `0.25`.

Is there a modifier I can add to make it just print `.25`, aka removing the 0?

Comment: if you're talking about C then all of the floating point output specifiers must have a digit before the decimal point (if a decimal point appears). You'd have to use a different solution, e.g. `%3d.%6u, ones, (unsigned int)(fabs(value) * 100000)`, or print to a memory buffer with `snprintf` and then drop the first digit.

Comment: To get a quality answer more info is needed: 1) How are `ones` and `value` related? Printing is inherently a rounding operation and that rounding may impact `ones` like in the case `value == 0.999`. 2) can `value` take on negative values.  3) What is the range of `value` (+0.00 to 0.99?), Nan, INF, etc.  4) Posting the higher level problem will result in even better answers.

Answer (score 1):

In C, no, there's not.

What you *can* do is print to a temporary buffer, then adjust what you print based on that:

```
char buff[30];
sprintf (buff, "%.2f", value);              // Get value to temp buffer
if ((buff[0] == '0') && (buff[1] == '.'))   // Starts with "0."?
    printf ("%s", buff+1);                  // Yes, skip the zero..
else
    printf ("%s", buff);                    // No, print the lot.
```

---

However, it *looks* like you always guarantee that the floating point is less than one, since you're running together the integer and floating point value in the output. If that's the case, you can possibly just use something like:

```
printf ("%6.2f", value + ones);
```

Comment: Good, but should use `snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.2f", value);` (not the deprecated and dangerous `sprintf`)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch  Looked through C11 spec - no sign `sprintf()` is depreciated.

Comment: `sprintf` is OK if used correctly, like any function. I'd agree with calling it "dangerous" for `%f` and `%d` though, and would also agree that `snprintf` is preferable.

Comment: See the *BUGS* section of [sprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sprintf.3.html).

Comment: While we're on the pointless pedantry topic, `strncmp` could be replaced with `memcmp` . In fact, `f` is guaranteed to output a decimal point when the precision specified was not `0` so you could just go straight to `printf("%s", buff + 1);`

Comment: +1 for the `printf ("%6.2f", value + ones);` which well addresses the higher level problem.

Comment: @Basile, it may well be dangerous if you don't know your locale and environment properties. However, "deprecated" has a very specific meaning in the standards world, and it's definitely not deprecated.

Comment: Ok, remove deprecated from my initial comment.